# Как открыть файл из winrar архива с помощью cmd?

Tags: cmd, powershell, rar, winrar

Имеется архив a.rar, в нем содержится файл b.pdf. Нужно открыть файл b.pdf из командной строки windows (cmd или powershell). Обычным способом это делается так: открыть архив, даблклик по файлу. Мне нужно сэмулировать это действие при помощи cmd или powershell.

Answer (score 0):

вы можете использовать утилиту 7-Zip. Если вы еще не установили 7-Zip, вам необходимо установить ее и добавить путь к утилите в переменную среды PATH.

Затем вы можете использовать следующую команду в командной строке:

```
7z x a.rar b.pdf -so | "путь_к_программе_PDF"
```

Здесь a.rar - это путь к архивному файлу, а b.pdf - это путь к файлу PDF внутри архива.

-so означает вывод содержимого файла в stdout (выходной поток), а "путь_к_программе_PDF" - это путь к программе просмотра PDF

Пример использования для 7-Zip и Adobe Acrobat Reader:

```
7z x a.rar b.pdf -so | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
```

либо же:
Чтобы открыть файл .pdf, который находится в архиве .rar, можно воспользоваться командой unrar e <path_to_archive.rar> [<path_to_output_folder>]. Если не указать [<path_to_output_folder>], то файлы будут извлечены в текущую директорию.

Таким образом, чтобы открыть файл b.pdf из архива b.rar, выполните следующие команды в командной строке (cmd или powershell):

1. Для cmd:

> ```
> unrar e b.rar b.pdf
> ```

2. Для powershell:

> ```
> & 'C:\Program Files\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe' e b.rar b.pdf
> ```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но не то. Мне нужно именно открыть файл внутри архива, без его распаковки.

Comment: @AnonChelovek - когда вы даблкликаете по файлу, то архиватор распаковывает во временный файл и открывает его.  Без распаковки это невозможно.

Comment: @ESkri Благодарю за ответ. Извиняюсь, что спустя столько времени. Теперь всё понятно.